# How to write "anni '90"

Tags: latex, pdflatex, xelatex

How is it possible to write "anni '90" in LaTeX?

Comment: What problem do you face when writing `anni '90`?

Answer (score -1):

If your goal is to write the [backtick](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Backtick) `` ` `` before the decade, just use it (no escaping is required):

```tex
anni `90
```

This is the result:

[image: Result]